# Using Apex Repeat to Populate a Visualforce Table

Tags: salesforce, apex, visualforce

It appears that my List is blank, not being passed through with the controller extension or otherwise some problem is causing my table not to populate the anticipated data.  This visualforce page is being loaded from a custom button on a Work Order.

I've tried populating the data by using:
:ApexPages.CurrentPage().getParameters().get('id')

As well as just hardcoding what I believe is the 'id' as shown in the code example.

The VF Page is as follows:

```
<apex:page Standardcontroller="WorkOrder" extensions="cWOInvoice1" renderAs="pdf">
    <apex:form >

...

              <table style="...">
                  <tbody style="...">
                  <tr style="display:table-row;">
                      <th style="...">Scope of Work</th>
                      <th style="...">Trade</th>
                      <th style="...">Price</th>                       
                      </tr>
                      <apex:repeat value="{!woli}" var="woli">
                      <tr>
                          <td style = "...">{!woli.Repair_Product__r.Name}</td>
                          <td style = "...">{!woli.Repair_Product__r.Trade__c}</td>
                          <td style = "...">${!woli.Item_Price_Roll_Up_Sub__c}</td>

                          </tr>
                      </apex:repeat>

                  </tbody>
              </table>
...
        </body>

    </apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

The controller looks like this (Again hardcoded workOrderID for bugtesting):

```
public class cWOInvoice1 {
    public WorkOrderLineItem woli {get;set;}
    public cWOInvoice1(ApexPages.StandardController controller){
        List<WorkOrderLineItem>woli=[SELECT Id, Area__c, Tenant_Responsible__c, WorkOrderId, Repair_Product__r.Name, Repair_Product__r.Bill_Rate_Retail__c, Repair_Product__r.Bill_Rate__c, Repair_Product__r.Trade__c FROM WorkOrderLineItem WHERE WorkOrderId='0WO55000000Cw4LGAS'];
    }
}
```

I expected the  custom controller to pass through a list of work order line items that apex repeat would then display in the table.  Instead, I get an empty table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the variable `woli` declared with two different types in different scopes.

At the controller level, `woli` is a single `WorkOrderLineItem` member variable:

```
public WorkOrderLineItem woli {get;set;}
```

Because it's never initialized, its value is `null`.

Inside your constructor, you re-declare `woli` as a `List<WorkOrderLineItem>` and initialize it:

```
public cWOInvoice1(ApexPages.StandardController controller){
    List<WorkOrderLineItem>woli=[SELECT Id, Area__c, Tenant_Responsible__c, WorkOrderId, Repair_Product__r.Name, Repair_Product__r.Bill_Rate_Retail__c, Repair_Product__r.Bill_Rate__c, Repair_Product__r.Trade__c FROM WorkOrderLineItem WHERE WorkOrderId='0WO55000000Cw4LGAS'];
}
```

This value goes out of scope at the end of the constructor and is never made available to your page.

You need to remove the local declaration and correct the type of the member variable.

Whether or not your `<apex:repeat>` currently compiles (I'm not sure if that's legal or not off the top of my head), you should change your iteration variable to have a different name than the bound property:

```
<apex:repeat value="{!woli}" var="woli">
```

You may wish to make the controller property something like `woliList` to clarify.

Comment: Thank you very much David!  Definitely an amateur mistake on my part declaring the variable twice in the constructor.  I made your suggested changes and got myself to a new error :).  Joys of learning a new language I suppose.